# How to fix whitespace when creating Laravel title?

Tags: php, laravel

I created such a field in my Laravel app.blade.php file.

```
<h1>@yield('heading')</h1>
```

I use this in my about.blade.php file as follows. (phpstorm default spacings)

```
@section('heading')
     TEST HEADING
@endsection
```

And I get an output like this. There's a lot of space and slack. If I write them side by side, I get a result like this;

```
<h1> TEST HEADING

</h1>
```

or such a result if i write no-space

```
TEST HEADING@endsection
```

What solution can be produced for this to be gapless and smooth?

Comment: Can you manually try adding spaces?

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi I can also add manually, output:
<h1> HEADING
      </h1>

Comment: Try using: `@section('heading')
     {{ 'TEST HEADING' }}
@endsection`

Comment: @section('notice'){{ 'TEST HEADING' }}@endsection
If I write like this, the problem is solved, thanks. So is this a correct usage? should I use it like this?

Comment: Does it wrap it inside your `h1` tags properly? If yes, you could go for it.

Comment: Yes working, thanks!

Comment: Posting it as an answer if in case someone stumbles around. Kindly upvote and mark as accepted if in case it helps! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could  write strings in this format:

```
@section('heading')      

   {{ 'TEST HEADING' }} 

@endsection
```

You could find more details here: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#displaying-data

Answer (score 1):

I guess I should use  tags in about.blade.php file.

```
@section('notice')
<h1>HEADING</h1>
@endsection
```

It seems to be resolved when I do this.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that there are no extra spaces or gaps around your heading when using the `@yield` and `@section` directives in Laravel's Blade templates, you can use the `@php` directive to write the heading without any extra whitespace or line breaks.

Here's an example of how you can modify your code to achieve a gapless and smooth heading:

In app.blade.php:

```html
<h1>@yield('heading')</h1>
```

In about.blade.php:

```html
@section('heading')
    @php
        echo 'TEST HEADING';
    @endphp
@endsection
```

By using the `@php` directive, you can write the heading directly without any extra spaces or line breaks. This will ensure that the output is gapless and smooth.

Alternatively, if you prefer to use Blade syntax instead of the `@php` directive, you can use the `{{ }}` tags to output the heading without any spaces:

In about.blade.php:

```html
@section('heading')
    {{ 'TEST HEADING' }}
@endsection
```

Both of these approaches will produce the desired result with a gapless and smooth heading.

Comment: ChatGPT generated answer